# creating Web API for a website or webpages

Tags: php, android, json

I am developing a website and an android app for a product service.I have made some web pages in PHP/Sql Server. I want to develop an API for my website/webpages but I am not able to understand how to go about developing the APIs.

I tried studying the link given below for APIs but it uses XML to develop it which is a little difficult to interpret as compared to JSON.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html#Introduction-APIMethods

I now have understanding about JSON after studying the example from this link but it just shows how to call data from the server using JSON.
http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_example.asp

Can someone refer me some links from where i can understand how to develop APIs(in JSON) for a website/webpage. Links with Examples would be a great help.

Thank You.

Comment: Asking for some links,books or any tutorials is off-topic at SO.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a simple page in PHP .../foo.php; return JSON data from it; instead of HTML. That is it. Nothing more. That is unless you want to do something like SOAP, where it is more involved.